# Is there a way to 'stack' popup instead of markers - leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm currently working on a web application where an estate agency can display its patrimony on a map (leaflet). I am using data provided by agency where there is different kind of patrimonies (Houses, Buildings, etc). However building rather means appartement, so you can have several appartement for a same address. And here's my problem, appartements' markers are stacking on the map, so there is just one marker which is available to user (and just one popup binded to only one marker among several ones). I would like to have one marker for X appartements but on click you can navigate through different popups related to all the appartements which have the same address.

I know that markerclusters could have been a kind of solutions by gathering the markers but it doesn't really suit to my superior

Here's an expected results found on another website [(https://imgur.com/a/46HPKXT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEvdj.png)

When I'm displaying patrimonies on the application, i'm selecting a city and this is requesting to my server all the patrimonies located in the city, when the list of patrimonies is received by client-side, it creates one-by-one every markers thanks to geoJson stocked with patrimonies and then displays all of them and this is where I'm blocked, I don't know how to manage to create only one marker for same-located appartement and in the same it make it fast enough for the user (upto 11k patrimonies can be requested at the same time)

thanks

Comment: How can you determine that your points should "merge" under the same Marker or Popup? Do they have an equal location in your data (address or coordinates)?

Comment: @ghybs in my database all patrimonies are stocked with a column "data" containing a geoJson point with their coordinates, it's those coordinates which are used to place markers on the map

Comment: Do they have the exact same GPS coordinate ? If so, on the client side you can create an array with all your latitude, longitude and ID in the loop. Then in the same loop you check if your current position already exist in this array. If this is the case then get the ID of the existing marker and merge with your new data. Don't really know if it will be expensive but maybe that's a solution.

Comment: Yes they do have the exact sames. I'll try it with the array but indeed I'm afraid it could be a little bit expensive with a lot of data, I'll tell you.
I was wondering :  does the includes() methods is able to check if an array exists in another array ?

Comment: Ok so the array method seems to work pretty well and seems not that expensive, just 200 milliseconds more than before using it when requesting all the patrimonies to display, thank you !